# What's the name of this DFS variation

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs, scheduling, depth-first-search

***Classical DFS:***

A set of tasks with precedence constraints (saying “u must be done before v”) are given. This problem can be represented by a directed graph. We assume that the graph is acyclic.
A DFS is usually used to find an ordering of the tasks that satisfies all of the precedence constraints, classical DFS algorithm can do it by building the sequence step by step.

***An extension:***

Consider now the following variation. Each node $j$ is weighted by a value $w_j$. When we are currently at node $j$, this weight will determine the next node to visit (the one with the higher weight).
[image: Example]

Moreover, imagine that each time a node is added to the list, we recompute the weight for the unvisited nodes using a given function (we don't care about the nodes that has already been added to the sequence).  Thus at step $t$, the $w_j(t)$  of node $j$ can be different from its weight at step $t+1$.

---

**Questions:** Is there a name of this problem ? How to solve it efficiently? (e.g If a node has several successors, one needs to determine the successor with highest weight, so which data structure to use?)

**N.B** The image is only used for an illustration purpose. The graph is **not** assumed to be a binary tree.

Edit: the graph is assumed to be connected

Answer (score 2):

This tree traversal sounds similar to a Best-first traversal where the heuristic function is based on your weight function `w`. This strategy uses a priority queue (e.g. a heap, in this case a max heap).

Consider the following algorithm. $G=(V,E)$ is a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$, $w(j,t)$ is the weight function taking a vertex $j \in V$ and a timestep $t$, and $S \subseteq V$ is the list of start vertices (one in each connected component of $G$). $G$ is not necessarily connected.

```
BestFirstTraversal(G=(V,E), w(j,t), S)
    visited = []
    t = 0
    
    # from [0, t):   heap is the order in which the vertices are visited
    # from [t, end]: heap is a max heap
    heap = S  # from t to the end is max heap
    
    # loop until all vertices have been visited
    while len(visited) != |V| do
        u = heap[t]  # get the max element
        
        # do something with u
        
        append u to visited
        append neighbors of u (not in visited) to heap
        t = t+1
        
        heapify(heap[t:])  # based on w at step t
    end while
end
```

Let $n = |V|$ be the number of vertices.

Run Time: `BestFirstTraversal` runs in $O(n^2)$.

Notice $S$ is a list of vertices, one for each connected component of $G$. This is necessary because there must be a starting point for each connected component. If we started from a single node in a graph with more than one connected component, we would never be able to visit the other connected components. Thus the loop will visit each node in $G$ from one of the starting vertices.

Thus the while loop runs $n$ times. Appending neighbors and heapify takes up to $O(n)$ work. Hence, $n * (2 * O(n)) = O(n^2)$.

Note, heap will contain the order of the vertices visited at the end `BestFirstTraversal`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think there is an error here, why would you append v to heap (before the while loop). We should be only interested in the neighbors. Am I wrong?

Comment: so what do the lines `for v in V do if v not in visited then append v to heap` do ?

Comment: I see the issue. This solution is correct, but before the for loop we need to "expand" `s` (the only vertex in the heap). In fact, the for loop is only there to handle case where `G` is disconnected.

Comment: Moreover, assuming that the graph is connected, nothing prevents the algorithm from jumping from s to a node v that is not a neighbor of s. Another issue, at each step we recompute the priorities of all the accessible and not visited nodes rather than only considering the neighbors of some node.

Comment: I made a modification to my solution, but I want to make sure I'm understanding the problem correctly. We visit each vertex in this manner: 
1) first visit s at time t=1, 
2) next visit a neighbor of s with the maximum weight (call it v) at time t=2, 
3) next visit a neighbor of s or v (that is not s or v) with the maximum weight at time t=3, etc.
Is this the correct way to interpret the problem?

Comment: Yup it is. But the graph is assumed to be connected. Thus, I think you can it more simple. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the for loop in `BestFirstTraversal`, since expanding `s` before the loop will result in the entire graph being visited. I only added that because I wanted the solution to be more general. The issue with the original solution was that I wasn't expanding `s` initially.

Comment: Could you please add to your answer also the case where the graph is not connected with its complexity?

Comment: I edited the answer. The time complexity is still the $O(n^2)$ except for the restriction that the starting node `s` has become a list of vertices `S`, one for each connected component of `G`. This allows the algorithm to jump between connected components for the next best vertex to visit.
Note, it is not as simple as running the algorithm on each connected component due to the change weights over time. This is what led to making `S` a list.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have a remark when you say  "t = 0" and then "# from [0, t):   heap is the order in which the vertices are visited" t is already 0 so [0,t) is empty I guess

Comment: Correct. Even though heap does have something in it at the beginning, I only count it when it has been visited. That's because the order could change. That being said, it might mean you must heapify before entering the loop.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that there is no more efficient algorithm ?

Comment: The lower bound on traversals is clearly $\Omega(n)$ since you have to visit every node. For best first traversals, the priority queue can be managed in a better way so you can get $O(n\log n)$. However, for this problem, the weights are dynamic. Thus, we must heapify the priority queue at each step (which can be done in $O(n)$). This results in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: I should point out that this is a greed algorithm, so this doesn't guarantee that the algorithm's traversal is highest cost. Imagine the case where an edge weight becomes massive after already picking it. However, this question wasn't about finding the highest cost. It was simply about a specific kind of traversal.

Comment: What do you mean by highest cost ?

Comment: If I got you right, if the weights are static, managing the priority queue is done in $O(n\log n)$ by removing the "heapify" line is your pseudo-code ?

Comment: By traversal cost, I mean cost if you add the weights as you visit nodes (the example in the question would be 3+3+2+1=9). By highest cost, I mean the maximum cost you could possibly get. The problem allows for dynamic edge weights, and since this algorithm is greed it may not traverse the graph such a way that it gets the highest cost. And with static weights, you are correct. You still have to manage a heap, but you can do so with inserts and deletes (which run in $O(\log n)$) instead of calling heapify. You do this for each vertex which nets you $O(n \log n)$.

Comment: @Tyler Would you mind taking a look at this question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129550/how-to-check-effeciently-that-some-changes-preserve-the-topological-ordering ? I would be grateful if you could help.

Comment: But here I guess you assumed that the graph is a tree. What about the case where two edges $(u,v)$ and $(w,v)$ point to the same node $v$ and $v$ is only accessible if both of its predecessors $u$ and $w$ are already visited ?